# EventEmitter al hacer Submit

Tags: angular

Buenas, me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Al hacer submit en el componente hijo y mandarle el objeto por parametro al componente padre por medio de un `EventEmiter`, la funcion que recibe el evento en el componente padre se ejecuta dos veces. Una con el objeto que yo le paso realmente y otro en la que recibe el evento `Submit`.

¿Esto porque ocurre? ¿Sugerencias?

*hijo.ts*

```
export class ProjectFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input()
    project: Project;
    @Output()
    submit: EventEmitter<Project> = new EventEmitter();
    formProject: Project;

onSubmit() {
        this.project = this.formProject;
        this.submit.emit(this.project);
    }
}
```

*hijo.html*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #projectForm="ngForm" *ngIf="formProject != null">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtName">Name</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="formProject.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtDescription">Description</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="formProject.description" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDescription" name="Description"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" (click)="clear()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

*padre.htrml*

```
<project-form  [project]="selectedProject" (submit)="onSubmitNotification($event)"></project-form>
```

Comment: Intenta quitar `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` del `form` y ponerlo en un evento `click` dentro de un botón. Para eso, comenta temporalmente el boton `type="submit"`. Me dices si se sigue comportando igual.

Answer (score 0):

Quita el input del hijo.ts e inicializa el objeto:

```
export class ProjectFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Output()
    submit: EventEmitter<Project> = new EventEmitter();
    formProject = new Project("nombre" , "descripcion");//inicializa el objeto con valores por defecto
onSubmit() {
    this.project = this.formProject;
    this.submit.emit(this.project);
    }
}
```

y del padre.html

```
<project-form (submit)="onSubmitNotification($event)"></project-form>
```

Comment: el input es porque el formulario tambien es de edición, no creo tenga algo que ver con lo q esta pasando